# Taking a photo with Camera and saving it to Gallery

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am trying to take a photo with the camera and save it to the Gallery.
This is what I have done so far:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main5Activity.this,
                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermissionID);

                    }
                }

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main5Activity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERM_WRITE_STORAGE);

                } else {
                    takePhoto();
                }
            }
        });


    }

public void initialze()
{
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
}
    public void takePhoto()
    {

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAPTURE_PHOTO);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case CAPTURE_PHOTO:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


        }

    }
```

I am having trouble writing the saving to gallery code. Where do I call the save to gallery function and is there an inbuilt function in android which helps me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `void initialze()` method call the `saveImagetoGallery`function:

```
public void initialze()
{
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
}
    public void takePhoto()
    {

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAPTURE_PHOTO);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case CAPTURE_PHOTO:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    saveImagetoGallery(bitmap); // Added this 
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


        }

    }
```

The `saveImagetoGallery` function is :

```
private void saveImagetoGallery(Bitmap finalBitmap){

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root+"/saveImage");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random random = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = random.nextInt(n);
        String imageName = "Image"+n+".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir,imageName);
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        if(file.exists())file.delete();
        try{
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,out);
            String string = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am assuming you have written the permissions in the `Android.Manifest.xml` file.

If you haven't, add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```